# How use modals in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 buttons, which call modal bootstrap window, when i do it the function load html-temptale with $scope's variables, but the modal window doesn't work with $scope, i asked this question before and there was the answer to use directives, but frankly speaking i don't understand how it works, here is an example

```
<div class="infBox" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="modal('Modals/modal2', row.Name)">
            <h4>BUILD</h4>
            <div>
                <img ng-class="{opac: row.Commit.Build.Debug == false}" src="IMG/computer-md.png">
                <img ng-class="{opac: row.Commit.Build.Release == false}" src="IMG/computer-md.png">
            </div>
            <span class="debug">Debug</span><span>Release</span>
            <span class="time">{{row.Commit.Build.Timefin}}</span>
        </div>
```

this is div-button

```
<div  class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
            <div  class="modal-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is modal window

```
$scope.modal = function(path, name){
    $scope.ModalObj = $scope.Objects[FindNumber(name, $scope.Objects)];
    $http.get(path).success(function(data) {
         $scope.modalData = data;
    });

};
```

this is a function to load temptale

```
<h4>BUILD</h4>
    <div>
        <img ng-class="{opac: ModalObj.Commit.Build.Debug == false}" src="IMG/computer-md.png">
        <img ng-class="{opac: ModalObj.Commit.Build.Release == false}" src="IMG/computer-md.png">
    </div>
    <span class="debug">Debug</span><span>Release</span>
    <span class="time">{{ModalObj.Commit.Build.Timefin}}</span>
```

this is temptale

Comment: in addition to @Sumeet Gohil answer, one more AngularJS modal implementation (without bootstrap markup, however) which deals with separate $scope inside a modal - https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This was your last post that and Nishi suggested you very well**!

[Problems with modal and ng-bind-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424926/problems-with-modal-and-ng-bind-html)

still if you don't understand then consider some suggestion.

1. Angular and jQuery works side by side either you can fill that gap or go with any one technology.
2. If you want to use Bootstrap Modal then you need to work with Angular Modal 
   https://github.com/btford/angular-modal
3. As Nishi Posted on your last post , I'll work fine you just need to change few lines.

   ```
   writeYourAppName.directive('modal', function () {
     return {
        template: 'Your Modal Window Code',
   ```

And use controller to pass values to model

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use [angular-ui modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).